# How to get or create on Django Rest Framework and return it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to send post request with json data as shown below.

```
{
  "checkin_date": "2022-02-15",
  "checkout_date": "2022-02-18",
  "guest_number": 1,
  "user": {
    "first_name": "Huesped",
    "last_name": "1",
    "email": "huesped_1@mail.com",
    "phone": "+34 12345678"
  }
}
```

How can I override some ModelSerializer method to get the user if the email exists, or create it and return its id for reservation related?

Can it be done in a single query with nested objects or should I do 2 queries?

Here are my python files.

models.py:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), verbose_name="User", related_name='user_reservations', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py:

```
class ReservationPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  user = UserPostSerializer()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

DRF serializers don't handle nested serializers so they have to be manually managed. For the case of creating a new model instance, you can override the serializer's `.create()` function and do the create manually.

There is `.get_or_create()` for django models that you can use for creating a new user, if it does not exist.

```
# serializers.py

from django.db import transaction

class UserSerializer(serializers.SeralizerMethodField):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone']

class UserPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    checkin_date = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d")
    checkout_date = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d")
    guest_number = serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserPost
        fields = ['checkin_date', 'checkout_date', 'guest_number', 'user']

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user', {})
        user_email = user_data.pop('email', '')

        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(email=user_email, defaults=user_data)

        validated_data['user_id'] = user.id
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

The code above is simply based on the response json data expected.